# jQuery autocomplete select ignores custom data fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

My controller returns a json object with the fields "id", "value" and an additional field "result_type". Unfortunately I'm unable to access this "result_type" field in the select method.

I'm using Rails 3.2.6 with the `jquery-rails` and `coffeescript` gems. In `application.js` I require `jquery-ui`.

```
$('#q').autocomplete
  source: (request, response) ->
  ...
  select: (event,ui) ->
    alert ui.item.value  (works)
    alert ui.item.result_type  (does not work)
  ...
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the returned JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `source:` section, I needed to add a line for result_type here:

```
source: (request, response) ->
  $.get .............
  response $.map data, (request_data) ->
  {
    label: request_data.value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>"),
    value: if request_data.id == "" then $('#q').val() else request_data.value,
    id: request_data.id
    result_type: request_data.resulttype
  }
```